# Simple Qt project with openCV instantly crash

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I try to use openCV in a Qt project. But my release build instantly crash on launch if I link the release libs of openCV. Debug libs allow the programm to start but the application crashes when I try to use openCV functions (it is known that mixing release/debug in openCV causes some crash).

So I made a simple project and it won't even launch. Both release and debug build crashes and using debugger causes a small window saying 'unexpected CDB exit'.

Here are the source.

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test_openCV
TEMPLATE = app

#flags to generate a .map file
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE +=/MAP
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += /debug

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        MainWindow.cpp

HEADERS  += MainWindow.h

FORMS    += MainWindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
INCLUDEPATH += "D:/openCV/build/include"

#Switching between handbuild and the build I downloaded have no effect.
#I am sure the path are good. Quadra checked.
#LIBS += -L"D:/openCV/build/x64/vc11/lib"
LIBS += -L"D:/openCV/hand_build/lib/Release"
LIBS += -L"D:/openCV/hand_build/lib/Debug"

#disables the "fopen not secure" warning in openCV.    
DEFINES += _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -lopencv_core2413 -lopencv_highgui2413 -lopencv_imgproc2413
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -lopencv_core2413d -lopencv_highgui2413d -lopencv_imgproc2413d
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <opencv/cv.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <QDebug>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //Removing this line will causes the program to start normally (guess it won't link the libs if nothing from openCV is used).
    cv::Mat image;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

What I get when launching app:

```
Starting D:\Colin\build_test_openCV\release\test_openCV.exe...
program suddenly ended
D:\Colin\build_test_openCV\release\test_openCV.exe crashed
```

I work on Windows 7 / MSCV2012 openGL 64bits / Qt 5.2.1 openGL.

Does anyone see a mistakes I could have made?

Comment: can you run this program under debugger?

Comment: @tty6 I wrote that when I do (pressing f5 under Qt Creator) I only get "The CDB process terminated". So I got no real information.

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar setup as yours and was getting the exact same problem. The issue was that the path to the corresponding dlls was not defined. These dlls:

- opencv_core2411.dll
- opencv_highgui2411.dll
- opencv_imgproc2411.dll

should be in D:/openCV/hand_build/bin/ (or maybe D:/openCV/hand_build/bin/Release/). Adding another line:

```
LIBS += -L"D:/openCV/hand_build/bin/Release/"
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar issue. The program was crashing because it could not find the appropriate DLL at runtime. Adding the OpenCV directories to my Windows PATH fixed the problem for me.

Comment: add Windows Path => Dll folder solve the issue for me, I follow the tutorial to build opencv with QT (with my QT opened before, this cause the issue), after successfully build opencv, I run the example without quit already opened QT, the program crashed, because, I set DLL path during the build opencv period, so, I need to close the QT and re-open QT to make it recognise the opencv build dll location.

Answer (score 1):

All items in your build must have been built using the same Visual Studio version, that means:

1. The Qt install you're using.
2. OpenCV.
3. Your code.

Most likely at least one of the above was not built using the same compiler. If OpenCV is linked against Qt, it must have been built against a binary-compatible version of Qt, too.

Comment: Qt is specific for a msvc version, so the project kit is using the same compiler, and I used that specific compiler to compile openCV (msvc2012 for all).

Comment: This is not true unless you are creating a plugin for Qt Creator. The OpenCV build and the Compiler used for running your code should be the same.

Comment: Where did Qt Creator even come into this question? The IDE is not relevant. Qt, OpenCV, and your code must be built using either the same compiler, or the compilers declared by the vendor to have binary compatible output. In case of MSVC, that implies same debug/non-debug runtime library choice, and compilers from MSVC 2017 onwards, since MSVC 2019 is binary-compatible with 2017 - largely. But sometimes it's not. So it's a problem. And certainly a MINGW Qt build won't work with MSVC built user code. Building Qt is a reasonably easy task, so I don't quite understand where the apprehension is.